# How to perform root level commands on Linux (Fedora) Live Media

Tags: linux, command-line, livecd, root

I need to use Live Media to make changes to a hard disk drive. I tried to `sudo` to no effect.

Seems like it would be troublesome to authorize root access on Live Media or have `sudo` allow commands such as `pvcreate`,`lvcreate`,`vgcreate`, especially if the hard disk is not encrypted.

Comment: Is `livecd` okay? Maybe you want to be more specific: What kind of hard drive? What commands are you trying exactly?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Something disk-oriented by the examples?

Comment: I'm trying to upgrade from F11-F15 but the Anaconda installer is not doing what I need it to do. I've [researched how](http://superuser.com/questions/311722/fedora15-help-me-understand-how-cryptsetup-and-lvm-interact), but my current idea requires disk formatting from the LiveMedia on the destination drive. As far as the commands, I've already listed them, there up there (^_^).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some distros do not use `sudo` as their method of rights elevation. Try using `su -` to become root and then doing whatever you need to do as root.

Comment: trying it right now...

Comment: `sudo` is a separate package in Fedora/Redhat. You can istall it if you want by becoming root and running `yum install sudo`.

Comment: That did it. No password required--you simply change users. (>_<)