# How do I become root user in bash?

Tags: bash, terminal, fedora, root

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to perform root level commands on Linux (Fedora) Live Media](https://superuser.com/questions/313455/how-to-perform-root-level-commands-on-linux-fedora-live-media)

I just installed F17 and am trying to learn the basics of bash.

All that I know for sure is that the dollar sign after [name@pc] means that I'm a regular user. Is this correct?

Comment: id mark this  close match to another post >> http://superuser.com/questions/313455/how-to-perform-root-level-commands-on-linux-fedora-live-media

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The super user (or administrator) usually is called `root` and has a user id of 0. You can check that by entering `id root`. This will show information about a user called `root`.

In order to become a super user, you can simply log on using the user `root`, if it is allowed. So where ever you initially are asked for a login and password, enter `root` and its password.

Usually, however, root login is disabled. In this case, a user uses `sudo` to run a program as root. `sudo bash` will open a root shell (bash) for you. But this only works if you are allowed to use `sudo`. Usually, this is the case if you are in the `sudo` group.

You can check the groups you are member of by simply using `id`, or `id your-username`.

How the prompt looks like totally depends on the user settings in `.bashrc`. By default, `$` is an ordinary user and `#` an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

The other option if you aren't already added to the `sudo` group is to run the command `su`. This will prompt you for the root password, and then give you a root shell (which will persist until you close the terminal/log out.)

Note that running a command with `sudo` will only run that single command as root. So if you run `sudo <some privileged command>`, it'll run  as root, but any commands you enter after that will still run as your normal user login.

One possible sticking point with using `su` to get a root shell: you may not know the root password. It may have been set during install, or, if root login is disabled, it may not be set at all. If you don't know the root password, you'll probably have to have to get `sudo` working, so that you can actually set the root password.